# paint program not saving edited picture

Tags: c#, image, paint

Am developing a paint application in C# , VS2010

The start-up interface is a blank `pictureBox` ,
I did a `mouseDown`  and a `mouseMove` event Handler for brush tool paint
and it works fine

When i try to save the new picture (After painting on the blank pictureBox)
I enter the file , and it's only a blank picture.

The problem is that the code is not saving the effects.

why?

**mouseDown event handler**

```
private void mouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (CurrentFunction == "DrawFree")
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
                ReleaseFlag = true;
            StartPoint = e.Location;
        }
    }
```

**mouseMove event handler**

```
 private void mouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (CurrentFunction == "DrawFree")
        {
            if (ReleaseFlag)
            {
                EndPoint = e.Location;
                g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
                g.DrawLine(p, StartPoint, EndPoint);
            }
            StartPoint = EndPoint;
        }

    }
```

**Save code**

```
 private void savePhotoToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.ClientSize.Width,
                            pictureBox1.ClientSize.Height))
        {
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            {
                Image yourImage = pictureBox1.Image;
                Bitmap yourBitmap = new Bitmap(yourImage);

                g.DrawImage(yourBitmap,
                            new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height),
                            new Rectangle(0, 0, yourImage.Width, yourImage.Height),
                            GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            }
            bmp.Save(@"d:\yourfile.png", ImageFormat.Png);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you Bitmapped "yourBitmap" with yourImage, try replacing bmp.Save with yourBitmap.Save

```
    yourBitmap.Image.Save(@"d:\yourfile.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

Comment: still , blank picture

Comment: I just edited my answer to "yourBitmap", is it still blank after this change?